# Common kinds of questions?

Tags: discussion

I feel like there are certain recurrent questions in terms of form. I think it could be a good community wiki to collect them here and to maybe compile best practices and guidelines for moderating, editing, and answering such questions.

Some examples:

"Is X legitimate?" It's common to hear people just want to know if a certain argument they have heard is "valid" or not.

"Should X?" If it is not the case that all "should" questions get closed as being opinion-based, then I think this type of question could use a little analysis as to what an ideal response should be. I don't know if I agree to the following, but to give an example, one could imagine a guideline like, "Ideally, should-questions should be in reference to a specific angle - i.e., would logical positivists agree to X, would Nichomachean ethics advocate X, would pragmatists agree that one should X, etc."

There are probably more, I just felt like opening this up for discussion.