# The “Is X justified/legitimate/reasonable?” question

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation, guidelines

Following up on [my stated wish to collect recurrent question types](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/common-kinds-of-questions), this post aims to focus on the question “Is X a good argument”?

Here is one example, please add more via edits or comments:

[Is non-physicalism reasonable?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/110276/is-non-physicalism-reasonable)

This happens enough that I suggest Article i:

*Article i: It is natural, understandable, acceptable, and pedagogically and theoretically valuable, to ask if a certain argument, theory, or belief, is a good one.*

This is followed by the observation that this question is born of the right motivation but might fail to actually achieve something useful, for a philosophy QA site:

*Article ii: The problem with this kind of question is it is not very answerable. (See question, “[What is answerability?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/what-is-answerability)”) While it may be for a variety of reasons one could have a complex discussion about, a couple simple, canonical reasons why are, i) it is a yes-no question, so it technically begets a trivial response; and ii) it seems apparent that it could invite an unbounded number of distinct answers, all of which reflect the personal convictions of each respective answerer. (See question, [What is canonicity?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/what-is-canonicity))*

Which leads me to the highly tentative:

*Article iii: Like the identifiable and named ‘XY-question’, this type of question could be tagged as a ‘value judgment question’, and routinely rephrased as, ‘What are the arguments for X?’ This is better than ‘closing as opinion-based’, which sounds like a forceful rejection of the question without a clear lead on how to revise it.*

Thus we might introduce a simple rule that “Is X good?” questions become “What are the arguments for X?”

All of the above claims are not beliefs I hold, they are suggested conjectures meant to stimulate conversation, for their dialectical value, to help us try to refine a picture of what factors are at play here.