# What is answerability?

Tags: discussion, questions

I invite a discussion about what identifiable characteristics an “answerable” question has - which ideally has some level of convergence amongst moderators and editors.

One obvious factor is, how many distinct answers would the question have?

3 + 3 = ? would have only one correct answer.

“What are the arguments for X?” could have anywhere from 1-3, up to perhaps 10-50 distinct answers, but I would find that to be an acceptably answerable question.

“What is time?” does not seem clear to me how many distinct answers it could acceptably have, but I am not sure that means such a question should not be allowed.